# Два адреса при обращении к указателю

Tags: c++, указатели, адрес

Есть код

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    bool *a = new bool(true);

    cout << a << endl;
    cout << *a << endl;
    cout << &a << endl;
}
```

И он выводит

```
0x4414f10
1
0x71d2e85b4548
```

Но что значат первое и третье число? Что из них адрес?

Comment: 1-я строка показывает адрес, по которому хранится переменная bool; 2-я строка показывает значение по адресу (т.е. значение переменной); 3-я строка показывает адрес, по которому хранится адрес, по которому хранится переменная bool (называется указатель на указатель). Из 1 и 3 оба являются адресами, только 1 указывает на переменную, а 3 указывает на 1

Answer (score 4):

Первое число - адрес созданной с помощью `new` переменной типа `bool`.
Второе - значение этой переменной.
Третье - адрес переменной, в которой хранится первое значение.

Comment: Что значит первое значение?

Comment: А как получилось, что они разной размерности? a - 32 битный, а &a - 64 или это следствие запуска на vm?

Comment: Размерность у них одна, только память под "true" была выделена в куче, а переменная "а" создана на стеке, по этому и адреса так сильно отличаются

Comment: @ffk, получается, что cout просто подрезал незначащие нули в начале, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @goldstar_labs правильно

Answer (score 2):

Можно с комментариями:

```
bool *a = new bool(true);
// занимаем память в размере sizeof(bool*)  с именем 'a', где записываем
//адрес обьекта, созданная  в динамической памяти
// и занятая нами память для указателья имеет адрес 
cout << "адрес в динамической памяти _ " << a << endl;
cout << "значение обьекта            _ " << *a << endl;
cout << "адрес в локальной  памяти   _ " << &a << endl;
```

указатель занимает память  в одно машинное слово. Это 4 байта или 8, зависит от машины.